# Working with .js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have my controller

```
def grafico_gantt 
    mapa = Hash.new
    mapa[:tasks] = [] 
    @projeto.atividades.each do |a|
        mapa[:tasks] << {
           id:a.id,
           descricao:a.descricao,
           status:a.status,
           data_inicial:a.data_inicial,
           tempo_gasto:a.tempo_gasto.to_i,
           data_final:a.data_final
        }
    end
end
```

And my archive .js.erb

```
<script>
 $(function() {
      var today = moment();
      var andTwoHours = moment().add("hours",2);
      var today_friendly = "/Date(" + today.valueOf() + ")/";
      var next_friendly = "/Date(" + andTwoHours.valueOf() + ")/";
      var maxDate = moment().add("days",10).toDate();

      $(".gantt").gantt({
        source: [{
            name: <%= raw @mapa[:descricao] %>,
            values: [{
                from: today_friendly,
                to: next_friendly,
                label:"Teste", 
                customClass: "ganttRed"
            }]

                }],

          });

    });

</script>
```

How make for the code name: `<%= raw @mapa[:descricao] %>`,
receive the controller value `mapa[:descricao] = a.descricao`,

I just show the value in variable name, replacing `<%= raw @mapa[:descricao] %>`

understood? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried define `@mapa` instead `mapa`?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7221957/413494) regarding performance of `.js.erb` files.

Comment: No, i fix a small problem in my controller...

I put @ in all mapa, for show in view... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

first of all turn mapa into instance variable(@mapa)

and then update js.erb file accordingly as given below.

```
<script>
 $(function() {
      var today = moment();
      var andTwoHours = moment().add("hours",2);
      var today_friendly = "/Date(" + today.valueOf() + ")/";
      var next_friendly = "/Date(" + andTwoHours.valueOf() + ")/";
      var maxDate = moment().add("days",10).toDate();

      $(".gantt").gantt({
        source: [{
            name: '<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:descricao] %>',
            values: [{
                from: today_friendly,
                to: next_friendly,
                label:"Teste", 
                customClass: "ganttRed"
            }]

                }],

          });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!! But, how i show all descricao??? This way just is show the first descricao... i have 3, how i make? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. on your controller:

> ```
> def grafico_gantt 
>     @mapa = Hash.new
>     mapa[:tasks] = [] 
>     @projeto.atividades.each do |a|
>         mapa[:tasks] << {
>            id:a.id,
>            descricao:a.descricao,
>            status:a.status,
>            data_inicial:a.data_inicial,
>            tempo_gasto:a.tempo_gasto.to_i,
>            data_final:a.data_final
>         }
>     end
>     respond_to do |format|
>       format.js
>     end
> end
> ```

on your view:

```
<%= @mapa[:task].first[:descricao] %>
```

Comment: OK! Thanks, almost all right!!! But i have a problem, i have 3 descricao for show, but the @mapa[:tasks].first[:descricao] show just 1. How i show all descricao? Thanks!!

Comment: @mapa[:task].map {|mapa| mapa[:descricao]}.join(', ')